# SQL Cannot add foreign key constraint.Do not know where the error is

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on learning sql and trying to make a database, but I am getting errors in this sql that I do not know why they are popping up.

```html
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  Fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Minit char,
  Lname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Ssn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Bdate date,
  Address varchar(30),
  Sex char,
  Salary decimal(10, 2),
  Super_ssn char(9),
  Dno int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
  Dname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Dnumber int NOT NULL,
  Mgr_ssn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Mgr_start_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber),
  UNIQUE (Dname),
  FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn)
);
CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS (
  Dnumber int NOT NULL,
  Dlocation varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber, Dlocation),
  FOREIGN KEY (Dnumber) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
  Pname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Pnumber int NOT NULL,
  Plocation varchar(15),
  Dnum int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Pnumber),
  UNIQUE (Pname),
  FOREIGN KEY (Dnum) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);
CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON (
  Essn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Pno int NOT NULL,
  Hours decimal(3, 1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Pno),
  FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (Pno) REFERENCES PROJECT (Pnumber)
);
CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT (
  Essn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Dependent_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Sex char,
  Bdate date,
  Relationship varchar(8),
  PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Dependent_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn)
);
```

Any help would be really good I have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: What errors are you getting? And are you using mySQL or MS SQL Server (they are different)?

Comment: I am getting the #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint and using mysql on wamp

Comment: This is not valid sql server syntax so I am guessing this must me mysql? Regardless of the DBMS you should NEVER store SSN in plain text. But you did you are learning so maybe this is just a project that is not a real application.

Comment: @SeanLange its just to try to learn how to write statements. What makes it not valid

Comment: I said it is not valid sql server syntax, then you said you are using mysql. They are not the same thing and the syntax is different.

Comment: You are creating Employee table with foreign key (Dno)  references Department(Dnumber), but department table doesn't even exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're referencing `department` from `employee` table and vice vera but when the database engines tries to create an `employee` `department` table doesn't exist just yet.

To fix this you can create an FK on `department` table once both tables created.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
  Dname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Dnumber int NOT NULL,
  Mgr_ssn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Mgr_start_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber),
  UNIQUE (Dname)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  Fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Minit char,
  Lname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Ssn char(9) NOT NULL,
  Bdate date,
  Address varchar(30),
  Sex char,
  Salary decimal(10, 2),
  Super_ssn char(9),
  Dno int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn);

-- rest of script
```

Here is a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e15ae4).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create all the tables first only with primary key and unique constraints. After that you can create foreign key constraints as below

Remove this line in first table creation

```
FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
```

Later add below line

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Employee
FOREIGN KEY (Dno)
REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
```

Comment: Does it matter what you call the constraint

Comment: you can just add foreign key without constraint name as well.